# Swift 4 can't dismiss and push a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 4 and I have got this following code:

```
let signInButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)
    button.titleLabel!.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlesignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handlesignIn() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("a")
    })
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Main(), animated: true)
}
```

Controller in which this code is written in is `UIViewController` and `Main` is `UITabController`. This code doesn't give me any error but it's not working neither. It doesn't even print `"a"`. Why is that?

AppDelegate:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = SignIn()
```

Comment: if you put a break point on the line `dismiss(animated: true, completion: {` does the breakpoint hit?

Comment: @NateBirkholz nope

Comment: Can we see how your button is set up? Is it in a storyboard or nib or is it programmatic?

Comment: @NateBirkholz it's programmatic,i have deleted the storyboard.I added button's full code.

Comment: Hmmmm... that button code works just fine for me. If you add this code, does it print "before"?:
`@objc func handlesignIn() {
        print("before")
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            print("a")
        })
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Main(), animated: true)
        }`

Comment: @NateBirkholz you commented the same code

Comment: Yes, I accidentally pressed ENTER instead of SHIFT-ENTER for a carriage return

Comment: @NateBirkholz it does print before and i checked again break point hits,but it still is not dismissing nor presenting `Main`

Comment: What if you just push the view controller instead of dismissing self?

Comment: @NateBirkholz still nothing.May `Main()` being a `UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate` be the problem?

Comment: Your code work perfect for me too. Can you upload your code somewhere I we will try to help you

Comment: @SvetoslavBramchev do you use XCode 9? I can send you whole project through email if you want

Comment: @NateBirkholz i tried the same code in another project it didn't work there neither

Comment: Any luck on this Saasa..?